# Using stdarg.h in bare metal programming

Tags: c, bare-metal, cortex-a

I'm writing a small bootloader for a qemu virt using cortex a72.
I am able to write some text to the UART contrôler to display some text.
I want to write a light version of printf to have some flexibility when writing text but stdarg seems not to work.

The compilation has no errors but when calling a function with variadic arguments, qemu seems to stuck itself in an infinite loop. When debugging with gdb, it wont leave the function and freeze even when using 'step' instead of 'next'.

Any way to use stdarg in bare metal programming or is a kernel needed ?

EDIT:
I just tried to debug using assembly layout and it is even more weird. At the beginning of the function, there is a bunch of 'str' to save some registers to the stack, but when executing one of them, the program jumps to a random memory address...
Here is what I see:

```
>0x400808b4 <printf>     stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-272]!
│   0x400808b8 <printf+4>   mov     x29, sp
│   0x400808bc <printf+8>   str     x0, [sp, #24]
│   0x400808c0 <printf+12>  str     x1, [sp, #216]
│   0x400808c4 <printf+16>  str     x2, [sp, #224]
│   0x400808c8 <printf+20>  str     x3, [sp, #232]
│   0x400808cc <printf+24>  str     x4, [sp, #240]
│   0x400808d0 <printf+28>  str     x5, [sp, #248]
│   0x400808d4 <printf+32>  str     x6, [sp, #256]
│   0x400808d8 <printf+36>  str     x7, [sp, #264]
│   0x400808dc <printf+40>  str     q0, [sp, #80]
│   0x400808e0 <printf+44>  str     q1, [sp, #96]
│   0x400808e4 <printf+48>  str     q2, [sp, #112]
│   0x400808e8 <printf+52>  str     q3, [sp, #128]
│   0x400808ec <printf+56>  str     q4, [sp, #144]
│   0x400808f0 <printf+60>  str     q5, [sp, #160]
│   0x400808f4 <printf+64>  str     q6, [sp, #176]
│   0x400808f8 <printf+68>  str     q7, [sp, #192]
│   0x400808fc <printf+72>  add     x0, sp, #0x110
│   0x40080900 <printf+76>  str     x0, [sp, #40]
│   0x40080904 <printf+80>  add     x0, sp, #0x110
│   0x40080908 <printf+84>  str     x0, [sp, #48]
│   0x4008090c <printf+88>  add     x0, sp, #0xd0
│   0x40080910 <printf+92>  str     x0, [sp, #56]
│   0x40080914 <printf+96>  mov     w0, #0xffffffc8
│   0x40080918 <printf+100> str     w0, [sp, #64]
│   0x4008091c <printf+104> mov     w0, #0xffffff80
│   0x40080920 <printf+108> str     w0, [sp, #68]
│   0x40080924 <printf+112> str     wzr, [sp, #76]
│   0x40080928 <printf+116> str     wzr, [sp, #72]
```

The program jumps at the `str q1, [sp, #96]` instruction.

EDIT2: As asked in the comments, here is a sample code that causes the bug. This code does nothing special, it just uses variadic arguments and the bug is still present.

```
int va_test(int arg1, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int next;

    va_start(ap, arg1);
    while (arg1) {
        next = va_arg(ap, int);
        arg1--;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return next; 
}

int kmain() {
    va_test(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is not generally some OS needed. We use it without OS as well. If you provide information about your compiler and how you use it, it might help.

Comment: According to cppreference, stdarg.h is one of the headers that is _supposed_ to be there even in a freestanding implementation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conformance#Fully_freestanding_standard_library_headers

Comment: I'm using gcc. Here is the compilation line I use: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -O0 -g -c kmain.c -o kmain.c.o

Comment: It would help if we could see a minimal but complete example of your C code.  You might be using the `stdarg.h` functions incorrectly.  You could compare the "miniprintf" code in [question 15.4](https://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html) of the [C FAQ list](https://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Just edited the post to add a sample code

Comment: Thank you for posting sample code.  Unfortunately (unfortunately for solving your problem, that is), I don't see any problems with it.  I compiled it on my system (using two different compilers), and it ran fine.  So this is a real mystery.

Comment: Could it be an emulation problem ?
The fact that qemu jumps to another address (always the same: 0x200) seems really weird to me.. Or maybe it's gdb that is not displaying the right code ?

Comment: This looks like C90. Did you actually #include <stdarg.h>? Otherwise C90 is happy to silently accept the code and then crash for you.

Comment: Yes it is included. I just tried without it to see if there is any difference and there is not, the assembly code produced is exactly the same. Doesn't gcc actually include his own version of stdarg.h be default when compiling with -ffreestanding ?

Comment: Yes gcc tends to include stuff implicitly but when running in C90 mode that also means that it assumes implicit int everywhere. As for what it does with -ffreestanding, I don't know, but stdarg.h is one of the mandatory headers even for freestanding implementations (which is a really stupid requirement from ISO C).

Comment: Anyway the best explanation of the bug you describe would be a stack overflow. As you can tell, variadic functions chew up stack space like crazy. Single step to the `str q1` instruction and peek at the stack pointer.

Comment: I investigated a bit deeper into the assembly, I don't see any reason why it could stack overflow. The compiler expands the stack by 256 bytes. It's big but not enough to cause a stack overflow. The sp register actually contains a correct value and the instruction causing the weird jump is not touching any space that is not in the stack space...
This bug is driving me crazy.
Btw, I uploaded a sample code that reproduce the error to github if someone wants to give it a try: https://github.com/JM445/weird_stdarg

Comment: Well what else could cause runaway code? Ye olde watchdog, accidentally activated ISRs, low supply... there's not much. I suppose linking printf itself incorrect might cause something like that too. Linking with/without floating point libs is a common problem but since you are using a high-end Cortex A, I don't see why you wouldn't want floating point libs. I guess it is karma/Murphy's law, for using stdio.h in embedded systems.

Comment: Hi, did you found the error? I'm facing exactly the same situation when I try to use variadic args in a bare metal kernel code. After the stack gets expanded 256 bytes the whole thing just die.

Comment: No sorry, this was a small sideproject I had for fun but I gived up on that front.